# Cannot import encfs folder into cryptkeeper

Tags: 16.04, gnome, encfs, cryptkeeper

I tried to set up an encrypted folder on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial with Gnome desktop. I know that encfs is not considered especially safe anymore, I decided to use it for my purpose anyway. Encrypting a folder with

```
encfs /home/xy/.hidden /home/xy/unhidden
```

worked fine. To add a little more usability to that, I installed cryptkeeper and started it. When I now try to import the newly created encfs-folder, I can see it in the file selection dialog, after enabling hidden files, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually select it for import. There's no "OK" or "Select" button when I highlight it. There's no difference if the folder is mounted or not. 
Is that a known bug of this combination or am I too dumb to select a folder?

**Edit**: Screenshot of dialog included.

[image]
In english: "Ordner anlegen" means "Create folder", "Abbrechen" is "Cancel" and "Vor" seems to be "Prev." in this context.

Comment: This is also the case when I try to create a new encrypted folder using cryptkeeper, as I just discovered.

Comment: @pomsky: Sure. Here you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vor" seems to be the right button here. In English version of the software, it's "Forward".

Comment: Ahhh. I see. You are right. It looked like it just brought me back one level up. But that's the next dialog already. Alright. Works now. So it's "to dumb to select folder".